# Link multiple table with math operation in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, inner-join

I'm trying to find the revenue from customers in an country (United States).
The relevant tables are: 
Order Details: Order ID, Unit price, quantity,
Orders: Order ID, customerID
Customers: customerID, country.

I'm not sure how to do this. I was thinking multiple inner join but it doesn't work. 
The error message is "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expession 'ORDER DETAILS].ORDERID = ORDER.ORDERID
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID = ORDERS.CUSTOMERID'
MS online said Error 3075

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY*UNITPRICE) AS Result
FROM [ORDER DETAILS]
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON [ORDER DETAILS].ORDERID = ORDER.ORDERID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID = ORDERS.CUSTOMERID
WHERE COUNTRY = 'Argentina'
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: table structure
http://postimg.org/image/oojygytkv/

Comment: share your table structure

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/od4f8bk1p/

Comment: basically how do I get the total revenue from X country.

Comment: It said syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't work for anyone. Explain your actual problem - is there an error or are you getting too many rows, not enough rows, incorrect results.

Comment: Still the same message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access if you are JOINing more than two tables together then it requires parenthesis.  Try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY * UNITPRICE) AS Result
FROM ([ORDER DETAILS]
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON [ORDER DETAILS].ORDERID = ORDERS.ORDERID)
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID = ORDERS.CUSTOMERID
WHERE COUNTRY = 'Argentina'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it now said syntax error in Join operation

Comment: I updated my answer.  You had `ORDER.ORDERID` when it should have been `ORDERS.ORDERID`.